# Does Firebase Hosting support rewrite rule to Python Cloud Function not deployed by Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Firebase Hosting can be configured to [direct requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#direct_requests_to_a_function) to a Cloud Function:

Will that work for a Python Cloud Function deployed directly to Cloud Functions, i.e., not using `firebase deploy`? That is particularly relevant for Python Functions, as Firebase can only deploy Node.js Functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've verified that this use case is supported.

You can deploy a python cloud function using the `gcloud` cli, and then deploy a url to your firebase hosting target that rewrites to this python function.

Here is an example `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "optional_target",
      "public": "public",
      "ignore": [
        "*"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "my_python_function"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Firebase requires a `public` directory even though it's unused in this case. So you can create a simple `public` directory with a `.gitkeep` file to make sure it's preserved in your source code repository. The `ignore` attribute in the `firebase.json` file makes sure that the `.gitkeep` file is not uploaded to firebase hosting.

For convenience, here is a simple bash script to deploy both the function and the hosting configuration in one command:

```sh
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
ORGINAL_PWD=$PWD

PROJECT_ID=$1

cd $DIR/../functions

gcloud functions deploy my_python_function \
  --project "$PROJECT_ID" \
  --runtime python37 \
  --trigger-http

firebase use $PROJECT
firebase deploy

cd $ORGINAL_PWD
```

In this case, the subdirectory `functions` contains a `main.py` module with the `my_python_function` defined.

Also to be clear, the use of `firebase use $PROJECT`, as well as defining a `target` in firebase.json, requires that a `.firebaserc` file be configured with the project/target mappings.